# ERROR: Operand missing for IN operator in argument to %EVAL function

Tags: sas, eval, sas-macro, in-operator

I can't understand this error in my case since i can execute the macro and it works perfectly and i try to run it again 10 minutes after it give me this error and sometimes i execute it four times the fifth one give me a correct result.
here is my code :

```
%let list = &Control_1. 
            &Control_2. 
            &Control_3.
            &Control_4.
            ;
%macro print_control_2(list) / minoperator ; 
%let Control_2=Control_2;

     %IF  &Control_2. in &list. %THEN %DO;
          proc sql;
          ...
         ;quit;
     %end; 
%mend;

%print_control_2(&list);
```

Comment: What do `&control_1`-`&control_4` resolve to?

Comment: actually it's a list to verify if the macro variable exist, since i have a lot of files and there is a specific list for every.

Comment: What have you set as the delimiter for macro IN operator?

Comment: None, and since it works some times i think that i shouldn't set a delimiter.

Comment: You need to know what delimiter it is using to understand whether it is going to see the right number of values on the right side of the IN operator. I think if you don't set the delimiter in the macro then what it uses will be based on the system setting, which could vary if you change it between calls. Are you positive you have values on both sides of the IN operator?

Comment: Is the point of the test to check if a macro variable exists?  Or are you testing if it has any value? Any value that is not all spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better practice to use `%symexist()` to check if macro variables exist to keep the log clean. If you have a list of variables to check, you can loop through your list of macro variables. By default, `countw()` and `%scan()` will see spaces as a delimiter.

```
%let list = Control_1
            Control_2
            Control_3
            Control_4
            ;

%let Control_2 = Control_2;

%macro print_control_2(list);
    %do i = 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&list.) );
        %let control = %scan(&list., &i.);

        %if(%symexist(&control.) ) %then %put &control. exists.;

    %end;
%mend;
%print_control_2(&list);
```

To solve your issue specifically, you will need to quote your list with `%bquote()` since it may contain unresolved macro variables. This can break the IN operator.

It is also recommended to always add `mindelimiter` with `minoperator` since users are able to set their own `mindelimiter` default with an autoexec. This will guarantee that your expected delimiter is always used.

```
%macro print_control_2(list) / minoperator mindelimiter=' '; 
     %IF  &Control_2. in %bquote(&list.) %THEN %DO;

        %put &control_2. exists.;

     %end; 
%mend;

%print_control_2(&list);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's exactly this is my issu (i have unresolved macro variables ) and the %bquote() resolved it so the macro works perfectly now. But still don't understand why it works sometimes and sometimes no without adding any modification

Comment: Could be that sometimes they all resolve and sometimes they don't in your environment. If you're running under the same exact parameters as above with multiple results then unfortunately I am not sure. It consistently gave me an error each time.